# 身近に親しい異性がいたらよかったのにね - Particle に

Tags: particle-に

> 身近[に]{L}親しい異性がいたらよかったのにね

What is the function of the particle に after 身近?

Comment: 身近に => “in proximity to me”

Answer (score 1):

This に is just a location marker. It's the same に as in 部屋に or 日本に. When used as a noun, 身近 refers to places near you, or familiar places you go to frequently (home, school, office, station, ...).

> 身近に親しい異性がいたらよかったのにね。
>
> It would have been nice for you/me to have someone of the opposite sex close by.